How to record audio from a meeting tab in google chrome?
I'm developing a React Chrome extension aimed at recording audio from specific tabs, particularly during meetings on platforms like Zoom and Meet. The primary goal is to facilitate the transcription of these conversations.
During my exploration, I experimented with "Loom." However, I encountered an inconvenience: when initiating recording, it triggers the opening of a separate tab for managing the audio recording process. This additional step disrupts the seamless experience I aim to provide. Subsequently, I investigated TacTiq, an alternative extension that impressively records meetings without necessitating the opening of any additional tabs. Despite this promising functionality, the inner workings behind its seamless operation remain a mystery to me.
While I've delved into the documentation provided by Chrome regarding extension APIs, I've yet to find a solution that addresses my specific requirements. I'm now seeking alternative avenues or insights to overcome this challenge. If you have any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this functionality or where I could further research, I would greatly appreciate your input.
I tried to read the chrome API documentation
